# How to create Zend MVC sub module and control (activate/deactivate) them dynamically?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, module

Is it possible to change the default Zend MVC structure like the following and somehow activate or deactivate the sub modules (profile/shop) in a main module (default)? Actually I want a plug me in type of interface where I can control a sub module to be available or not. Is there any better approach to reach my goal (plug me in style module)?

```
application

--admin
----user
------controllers
------forms
------views
----banner
------controllers
------forms
------views
----category
------controllers
------forms
------views
----product
------controllers
------forms
------views
----shop
------controllers
------forms
------views

--default
----profile
------controllers
------forms
------views
----shop
------controllers
------forms
------views
----blog
------controllers
------forms
------views

--layouts
----admin
------scripts
----default
------scripts

--models
```

In the above structure I have two modules admin and default. I need to divide them in sub modules like [ profile,shop,blog ] for default module and [ user,banner,category etc. ] for admin module. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can probably use Zend_Router for that : when a module must be made unreachable, you add a route that redirects to another page/module (maybe a 404 page), and when the module must be back online, you just remove the previously created route.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html